# How to stop Atom grammar effecting certain lines

Tags: atom-editor, grammar

This is a bit of a weird question, but I only ask on SO because of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20251/where-to-ask-a-question-about-an-ide).

#### Some Context

I'm refactoring and thought it'd be great utility if I could merge two JavaScript files. One file is *original* and the other has a *few tiny changes* - though the process of manually editing takes time and can cause potential unexpected issues in the future. It's annoyingly repetitive.

One solution I considered was a text templating system, where exterior variables are presented and the output is changed when served to the client (it's run through a CDN). For instance, instead of having two different files with minute changes such as:

```js
const MAXIMUM = 5;
```

and

```js
const MAXIMUM = 100;
```

It could be done like:

```
<% if (type === "capped") { %>
  const MAXIMUM = 5;
<% } else { %>
  const MAXIMUM = 100;
<% } %>
```

But, my Atom grammar for JavaScript would mess up and ruin the rest of my file. In the last example presented, I'd wish to be able to stop the Grammar from interpreting line 1, 3 and 5.

> **Simply:** is it possible to exclude certain lines of JavaScript from being interpreted by Atom's currently-selected Grammar.

Comment: Note also that I do know how to program. This question is instead the pursuit of parsing a file so that it can be served to different types of customers dependent on external variables, and being able to faciliate that inside Atom :P

Comment: Seeing the example, I could think of several other ways to achieve the same. But maybe the example gives too limited insights of what you're trying to do. Is it really just values you need to change? I think that changing the syntax grammar should be the last resort.

Comment: @idleberg I think that I've found an alternative grammar which was built for Ruby that allows me to do the same thing, so it's no big issue - but other people could have the issue.